# Kafka Connect to Hive in HDFS - No data loaded into table

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hive, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

I have Kafka Connect set up to dump data from my Topic into HDFS with Hive enabled:

```
"confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "kafka-1:19092,kafka-2:29092,kafka-3:39092",
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs3.Hdfs3SinkConnector",
"flush.size": "3",
"hdfs.url": "hdfs://namenode:9000",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"logs.dir": "logs",
"name": "kafka to hdfs - repos",
"topics": "repos",
"topics.dir": "topics",
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
"hive.integration": "true",
"hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://hive-metastore:9083",
"schema.compatibility": "BACKWARD"
```

When running the task, data is sent to HDFS:

```
# hdfs dfs -ls /topics/repos/partition=0
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   3 appuser supergroup        281 2022-12-02 13:42 /topics/repos/partition=0/repos+0+0000000000+0000000002.avro
-rw-r--r--   3 appuser supergroup        294 2022-12-02 13:42 /topics/repos/partition=0/repos+0+0000000003+0000000005.avro
-rw-r--r--   3 appuser supergroup        283 2022-12-02 13:42 /topics/repos/partition=0/repos+0+0000000006+0000000008.avro
```

And the table is created in the Hive metastore:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> show tables;
+-----------+
| tab_name  |
+-----------+
| repos     |
+-----------+
```

But for some reason the table is empty / no data loaded from the HDFS files:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> select * from repos;
+------------------+------------------+
| repos.repo_name  | repos.partition  |
+------------------+------------------+
+------------------+------------------+
```

When looking at the configuration of the generated table, it looks like the hookup is fine:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> DESCRIBE FORMATTED repos;
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|           col_name            |                     data_type                      |           comment           |
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| # col_name                    | data_type                                          | comment                     |
|                               | NULL                                               | NULL                        |
| repo_name                     | string                                             |                             |
|                               | NULL                                               | NULL                        |
| # Partition Information       | NULL                                               | NULL                        |
| # col_name                    | data_type                                          | comment                     |
|                               | NULL                                               | NULL                        |
| partition                     | string                                             |                             |
|                               | NULL                                               | NULL                        |
| # Detailed Table Information  | NULL                                               | NULL                        |
| Database:                     | default                                            | NULL                        |
| Owner:                        | null                                               | NULL                        |
| CreateTime:                   | Sat Dec 03 11:46:56 UTC 2022                       | NULL                        |
| LastAccessTime:               | UNKNOWN                                            | NULL                        |
| Retention:                    | 0                                                  | NULL                        |
| Location:                     | hdfs://namenode:9000/topics/repos                  | NULL                        |
| Table Type:                   | EXTERNAL_TABLE                                     | NULL                        |
| Table Parameters:             | NULL                                               | NULL                        |
|                               | COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE                              | {\"BASIC_STATS\":\"true\"}  |
|                               | EXTERNAL                                           | TRUE                        |
|                               | bucketing_version                                  | 2                           |
|                               | numFiles                                           | 0                           |
|                               | numPartitions                                      | 0                           |
|                               | numRows                                            | 0                           |
|                               | rawDataSize                                        | 0                           |
|                               | totalSize                                          | 0                           |
|                               | transient_lastDdlTime                              | 1670068016                  |
|                               | NULL                                               | NULL                        |
| # Storage Information         | NULL                                               | NULL                        |
| SerDe Library:                | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe | NULL                        |
| InputFormat:                  | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat | NULL                        |
| OutputFormat:                 | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat | NULL                        |
| Compressed:                   | No                                                 | NULL                        |
| Num Buckets:                  | -1                                                 | NULL                        |
| Bucket Columns:               | []                                                 | NULL                        |
| Sort Columns:                 | []                                                 | NULL                        |
| Storage Desc Params:          | NULL                                               | NULL                        |
|                               | serialization.format                               | 1                           |
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I can't seem to find any errors being written anywhere in the logs. I think it could be related to the sub-folder "partition=0", but I am not quite sure how Hive deals with this.

Maybe I am lacking something in the configuration? Or there is something special that has to be done for the data to be loaded?

Comment: Please show the full table description. Is it `PARTITIONED BY partition`? Also, did you try running `MSCK REPAIR repos`?

Comment: Full description added. The following seems to fix it: MSCK REPAIR TABLE repos;

Comment: Still not sure why it is necessary to repair the table. Does this indicates that the setup is correct, but that Hive is not 100% ready to ingest?

Comment: The msck command syncs the hdfs filesystem with the Hive metastore. So, either there's some error with your metastore config value, or just Kafka Connect doesn't update the metastore with each partition after writing the data. Also, the partition data type should probably be integer rather than string... Also, your table should be defined as AvroSerde, not Parquet